# How to store data in sqlite3 in a time stamped way per PK, per FK?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

first let me say I'm not a DB guy, I have done some things before and I feel like a DB is the best way for me to do what I'm trying to do so I need some help..

What I'm trying to do is to make a script that will poll a device and and scrape some data from it.  I have no issues getting the data, it how to store and reference it. Below is a sample of structure I am dealing with.

```
Parent_Data_1
    Child_Data_1
        Timestamp1 = 5646
        Timestamp2 = 5489
        Timestamp3 = 42322
    Child_Data_2
        Timestamp1 = 5654643346
        Timestamp2 = 5442389
        Timestamp3 = 422322

Parent_Data_2
    Child_Data_1
        Timestamp1 = 564576
        Timestamp2 = 54812959
        Timestamp3 = 422
    Child_Data_2
        Timestamp1 = 5654643346
        Timestamp2 = 5442389
        Timestamp3 = 422322
```

So I basically have a parent devices that has multiple child devices in it.  I want to pull some stats every hour for each child devices and record them.

After 24 hours I want to know the highest integer that was recorded in the last 24 time stamps per child device.  So in this example Parent_Data_1,Child_Data_1,Timestamp3 would be the highest for that Child_data.

I can figure out all of that other than how to structure the DB, I want to do this in SQLite3 as my poller will be in python3 and I dont want to have to setup a DB server.  Again I can get all the data and the math its just how to set it all up.

More info:

- Parent_Data_# would be the Primary key
- Child_Data_# is the data point

Overall at the end of the day I would need to see something like this:

- Parent_Data_1 - Child_Data_1 - Had a Max of 42322 in the last 24 hours
- Parent_Data_1 - Child_Data_2 - Had a Max of 5654643346 in the last 24 hours

Anyone have any tips for this, I know a little DB, but I'm not that great!!

Answer (score 0):

A primary key would be unique for each row. But you have multiple measurements for the same parent device, so this cannot be the PK.

Just use a table with four columns:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ScrapedValues (
    Parent,
    Child,
    Timestamp,
    Value
);
```